# bootstrap datepicker gets date wrong if its the string month

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

When using this bootstrap datepicker, it works fine, except in a textbox, if the existing date happens to be written out in string form for the month, it puts the current month there instead, its September now, so if it says "June 1, 2014" datepicker pops up and says "September 1, 2014" in its image and inserts 9/1/2014.

imagine a textbox that contains the literal string:  July 4, 1976

when clicking in the text area, the month datepicker shows up, and it has the day right and year right, but it says "September" as the month.  As if it does not read the string month thats there?

Comment: Because it doesn't work with anything but whatever `format` is in the settings.

Comment: if the format is changed to fit July 4, 1976, MM/d/yyyy then if clicked it does show the datepicker calendar right, but it leaves it July/4/1976 instead of making it the proper format of 07/04/1976